# C function to read character

Tags: c

Is there a C function used to read characters from keyboard that does not return newlines ?

I have tried `getchar()` and `scanf()` .But both of it failed.

Please tell me if there is a function.

Comment: can't you just check whether getchar return is equal to newline and filter it out?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114301/raw-terminal-mode-how-to-take-in-input

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. VTC.

Comment: What do you want to read from the input stream?

Comment: scanf() always skip the newline characters, how you checked show it

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Comment: Should the newline be silently discarded or should it be left in the input stream?

Answer (score -1):

`scanf()` receives until a spacebar is entered ie.only one string is accepted . This can be overcome by using

`scanf("%[^\n]s",str);`.

It waits until newline is entered. `gets()` is also an alternative to receive string until newline is entered.