# How to check if character read in through read system call is a backspace?

Tags: c

I have the following piece of code which reads in a character using the read system write call:

```
char character;
read(STDIN_FILENO, &character, 1);
```

How do I detect whether `character` is a backspace or not? Based on that, I need to delete the last character from the console output.

Comment: Backspace is ASCII character 8.

Comment: @KenWhite So it's as simple as if (character == 8)?

Comment: I'd guess you could try it yourself and find out, couldn't you? :-)

Comment: @KenWhite It doesn't seem that if (character == 8) detects whether the backspace is pressed or not unfortunately.

Comment: I suppose that you need a keyboard hook here, not a function that reads a character; If you're running windows, then something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975916/global-keyboard-hook-with-wh-keyboard-ll-and-keybd-event-windows

Comment: Did you try `char(8)`? ASCII 8 is the backspace character - you can read it yourself in any ASCII chart. It will be labeled as `BS` for `BackSpace`. Google it.

Comment: @IvanSilkin I am on linux.

Comment: @KenWhite I have tried if (character == 8), if (character == '\b'), and even if (character ==  0x08), all to no avail. Is the problem related to the fact that I am using the read system call?

Comment: You could print _any character_ that you read and check the different codes for the keys you pressed. If BS is not read, the mode of the terminal is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if it's a backspace by looking for character number 8 (ASCII). It's written in C as '\b'.

However did you forget to put your terminal in RAW mode?

To change terminal to raw mode, see this answer to a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129698/14768 ; the code you want is in function `changemode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <winuser.h> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(8)) //checks to see if the input contained any backspaces
    {
        cout<<"Backspace was detected"; 
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Backspace Not detected";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

or similarly using a character:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <winuser.h> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    char c;
    cin.get(c);
    
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(8)) //checks to see if the input contained any backspaces
    {
        cout<<"Backspace was detected"; 
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Backspace Not detected";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I now realised you are using C instead of C++ so all you do is change the libraries you are using.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState doesn't exist. See OP's comments. " I am on linux. "

Comment: @Joshua that comment was not there prior to writing my proposed solution.

Comment: I beg to differ. It was there before I wrote my answer and my answer sorts above yours when I sort by oldest.

Comment: @Joshua, I opened answer tab before any replies were opened on your parent post because I was testing out many solutions out before I posted. During that time, it could be that you replied within that timeframe. I assumed it was Windows because the majority uses windows. But this solution is not incorrect , it's just not compatible with your OS.

Comment: Ah I get it. Comment was posted while you were typing answer.